# Como obter a diferença entre datas e transformar em horas?

Tags: mysql

No MYSQL, sei que posso retornar uma diferença entre datas através da função `DATE_DIFF`.

exemplo:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), created) <= ?
```

Porém, eu preciso que nesse `DATEDIFF` seja retornada a diferença em dia convertida para horas. Pois eu preciso comparar essa diferença para saber se um determinado prazo já venceu (e esse prazo é em horas, não em dias).

Como posso obter o valor em horas de um `DATEDIFF` no MYSQL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma boa opção neste caso é usar `TIMESTAMPDIFF(unidade, datetime1, datetime2)`, que já dá o resultado na medida desejada:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, created, NOW() );
```

Você pode usar outras medidas no lugar de `HOUR`, dependendo da necessidade:

- `MICROSECOND`
- `SECOND`
- `MINUTE`
- `HOUR`
- `DAY`
- `WEEK`
- `MONTH`
- `QUARTER`
- `YEAR`

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Answer (score 8):

Use a função [timediff()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) ele é parecida como `datediff()` porém retorna o tempo(hh:mm:ss) de duas datas. Para comparar apenas a hora, use função `HOUR()` dessa forma apenas a hora é retornada, como no terceiro exemplo.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW(), created) <= ?

SELECT TIMEDIFF('2016-06-16 00:00:00', '2016-06-15 13:20:51') //10:39:09

SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2016-06-16 00:00:00', '2016-06-15 13:20:51')) //10
```